# CXF 2.7.16: ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE114 field name is invalid; jaxws_asm

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, websphere, cxf

We upgrade CXF from v2.2.6 to v2.7.16. When we start IBM WebSphere Application Server v7.0.0.33 in Linux machine, error is reported for **jaxws_asm**/RetrieveRssFeedResponse:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE114 field name is invalid; class=com/abc/mobile/service/rss/jaxws_asm/RetrieveRssFeedResponse, offset=0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:287)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:224)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper$TypeHelperClassLoader.defineClass(ASMHelper.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper.loadClass(ASMHelper.java:316)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.createWrapperClass(WrapperClassGenerator.java:229)
```

Here is our current understanding:

- This error does not occur in local Windows machine WAS7.0.0.11
- Class jaxws_asm.RetrieveRssFeedResponse does not exist at compile time. Instead, it's generated by CXF at runtime.
- Our application code has Java package: com/abc/mobile/service/rss
- Class WrapperClassGenerator in org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle.jar/2.7.16 appends Java package “jaxws_asm” at line 160:

  String pkg = new StringBuilder().append(getPackageName(method)).append(".**jaxws_asm**").append(anonymous ? "_an" : "").toString();
- Our application code com.abc.mobile.service.rss.GlobalProductRssService.java has:

  @WebMethod(operationName = "retrieveRssFeed")
- Class WrapperClassGenerator in org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle.jar/2.7.16 appends class name “Response” at line 164:

  className = new StringBuilder().append(className).append("**Response**").toString();
- We tried to add asm/asm.jar/3.3.1 to WEB-INF/lib or WAS7.0/java/jre/lib/ext. It did not help.
- We have enabled class loading trace log by following IBM MustGather document: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21196187.

Trace log shows that "**jaxws**.RetrieveRssFeedResponse" is being loaded:

```
[1/5/16 11:39:04:447 EST] 00000014 CompoundClass >  loadClass com.abc.mobile.service.rss.jaxws.RetrieveRssFeedResponse this=com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@736d736d[PL][war:US-EAR/US.war] Entry
[1/5/16 11:39:04:447 EST] 00000014 CompoundClass >  loadClass com.abc.mobile.service.rss.jaxws.RetrieveRssFeedResponse this=com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@70207020[app:US-EAR] Entry
[1/5/16 11:39:04:448 EST] 00000014 CompoundClass <  loadClass com.abc.mobile.service.rss.jaxws.RetrieveRssFeedResponse failed Exit
[1/5/16 11:39:04:448 EST] 00000014 CompoundClass <  loadClass com.abc.mobile.service.rss.jaxws.RetrieveRssFeedResponse failed Exit
```

I have not found out why the above class loading trace log loads "**jaxws**.RetrieveRssFeedResponse". It's highly appreciated if anyone could share any clue about how to solve this ClassFormatError.

Comment: It's possible this is a JVM bug, but I suspect CXF is generating an invalid field name (e.g., containing `-` due to some XML element).  It's unfortunate the JVM error doesn't include the field name, so you could try to open a PMR with IBM for that, but it's probably easier to modify the `ASMHelper$TypeHelperClassLoader` CXF class to dump the class bytes being defined and then inspect them yourself to see what field names are being defined/referenced.

Comment: Thanks @Brett Kail. ASMHelper.java line 367 has only class name: 
`    ret = super.defineClass(name.replace('/', '.'), bytes, 0, bytes.length);`
I am thinking maybe I can modify WrapperClassGenerator.java to use asm.jar directly.

Comment: My suggestion was to change that line of code to write those bytes to a file so that you can inspect them (e.g., using javap) to see if the generated class bytes attempt to define a field with an invalid name (e.g., containing `-`).

Comment: Hi @BrettKail, I have modified CXF/2.7.16/ASMHelper.java and printed all generated classes.RetrieveRssFeedResponse.class has only 1 field with "[]" in field name. Does it mean that JAXB does not support "[]" in field name?
  @XmlElement(name="RssChannelDTO[]")
  private RssChannelDTO[] RssChannelDTO[];

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with JAXB, but `[` and `]` are not valid characters in an XML name.  Is JAXB supposed to specially handle that?  If yes, I guess CXF needs to mangle the name when generating the class bytes.  Otherwise, it looks like you're using an invalid element name (although it also seems like an issue in JAXB or CXF of romsething for not diagnosing the problem with a good error message prior to generating class bytes).

Comment: I have modified WebResult annotation to remove "[]". Now the error is gone. Anyway, several new errors are reported. We are trying to solve all new errors and then do some sanity test. Once we confirm that everything is working fine, I will post my analysis and solution. Thank @BrettKail very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your help. The issue has been solved by removing "[]" from @WebResult annotation. In other words, originally our application code has:

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "retrieveRssFeed")
    @WebResult(name = "RssChannelDTO[]")
```

The error is solved by changing it to:

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "retrieveRssFeed")
    @WebResult(name = "RssChannelDTO")
```

What we have done is:

- Modify CXF/2.7.16/ASMHelper.java defineClass() method to print the dynamically generated classes. Totally 302 classes have been printed out.

  ```
          System.out.println("***********ASMHelper.TypeHelperClassLoader.defineClass(): " + name.replace('/', '.'));
          try {
              java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(name.replace('/', '.') + ".class");
              fos.write(bytes);
              fos.close();
          } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
              ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
  ```
- Among all 302 generated classes, only RetrieveRssFeedResponse.class has "[]" in field name

  ```
          @XmlElement(name="RssChannelDTO[]")
          private RssChannelDTO[] RssChannelDTO[];
  ```
- Modify CXF/2.7.16/ASMHelper.java to add main method (because constructor of inner class TypeHelperClassLoader is private) to call loader.defineClass() method
- After running main method, error is reported:

  ```
          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field name "RssChannelDTO[]" in class RetrieveRssFeedResponse
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
              at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper$TypeHelperClassLoader.defineClass(ASMHelper.java:377)
              at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper.main(ASMHelper.java:513)
  ```
- Then we modified our application code to remove "[]" from @WebResult annotation. The generated RetrieveRssFeedResponse.class has:

  ```
          @XmlElement(name="RssChannelDTO")
          private RssChannelDTO[] RssChannelDTO;
  ```

Now error is gone and our WebSphere Application Server v7.0 can be started without any error.

Regarding the IBM class loading trace log shows only "jaxws.RetrieveRssFeedResponse", I guess the situation is:

- IBM logging statement might ignore "_" and anything after it during logging
- But IBM class loader can still load "jaxws_asm.RetrieveRssFeedResponse"

Anyway, this is only my guess and I have not checked any IBM source code.